# UIAlertController executes handler immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have problem with [uialertcontroller](/questions/tagged/uialertcontroller). [uialertview](/questions/tagged/uialertview) works perfectly but this just won't. I have this:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Success")
                                                                                     message:LocalizedString(@"Example") preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Ok")
                                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
                                                                 {
                                                                     [self performSelector:@selector(presentLogInViewController) withObject:nil];
                                                                 }];
                                                            }];
[alertController addAction:actionOk];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Message is shown for two seconds and executes handler immediatly. I want to handle when button Ok is pressed but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm... Are you 100% sure the alert's handler is being executed without OK being pressed? Perhaps there's something else in your code elsewhere that's performing those actions...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have delegate for AlertView but I have everything checked. AlertView works, this does not

Comment: How are you sure? What specifically have you done to check?

Comment: I have version of the app checked, in delegate I have index of button checked, and I have commented out and erased AlertView delegate to check and it does the same thing.

Comment: Could you please try to add a simple `NSLog(@"test");` just before the call to `dismissViewController`? This way you'll be sure that it is indeed the handler's fault. But if `test` will not be printed, you should look for the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have reset my simulator and closed and opend my xcode. Now, everything works. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dismiss block and then the handler will be called on click of OK button.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Success")
                                                                         message:LocalizedString(@"Example")
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Ok")
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                      [self performSelector:@selector(presentLogInViewController) withObject:nil];                                                                
                                                 }];

[alertController addAction:actionOk];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code

```
UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                       {
             [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                       }];
        [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
        [self presentViewController: alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Same thing, two seconds message and it goes away

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to dismiss the alert controller from inside the completion block because it will dismiss automatically.

```
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                   message:@"This is an alert."
                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
     // here you can add the completion for when the OK button is pressed
}];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For each action you add using the `addAction:` method, the alert controller configures a button with the action details. When the user taps that action, the alert controller executes the block you provided when creating the action object.